# MS-Access Tab control direction

Tags: user-interface, tabs, ms-access-2013, right-to-left

any one tried to flip MS Access Tab control direction.

I want to change the direction to be from right to left. such that the first tab will be on the right.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this myself but there is an option for it:

File, Options, Client Settings, Default Direction: Right-to-Left

If you go to the properties of individual tables there is a Right-to-Left option.

Comment: unfortunately, the Default Direction in does not affect the direction of tab control. actually, my default direction is rtl.

Comment: Each table and query has an Orientation option in the property sheet. In the design view click on the Design tab and select "Property sheet". The orientation is in there.